# Create socket function returns -1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, udp, winsock

I am new to socket programming. I am trying to create an UDP Socket but the `socket()` function returns -1

```
signed long int sockfd;
sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);       //socket Function returns -1 Value
```

Can you tell me when this socket function returns a -1 value?

Comment: That may be a silly question, but you did call `WSAStartup`, didn't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call WSAGetLastError() to find out more about the error. I guess you didn't call WSAStartup().

That said, there is a SOCKET type, which you should use instead of "signed long int", and compare to INVALID_SOCKET instead. These are subtle differences between WinSock and the BSD sockets API. If in doubt, always check out the documentation at Microsoft's.

Comment: `socket()` returns `INVALID_SOCKET` on error, not `SOCKET_ERROR`.